# Drools 5 - Date comparison

Tags: java, date, drools

I am trying to compare a Java class function date with current date. I need to verify the Java class date(CreationDate function) should be older than [3 months] than the current date.

JAVA -

```
public class PersonPer 

  ....
 public Date getCreationDate() {
    return creationDate == null ? null : new Date(creationDate.getTime());
}

public void setCreationDate(Date creationDate) {
    this.creationDate = creationDate == null ? null : new Date(creationDate.getTime());
}
```

....
Junit for testing -

```
  PersonPer personPer=new PersonPer();

    String personCdate="15/12/1998";
    Date personCreationDate = null;

    try {
        personCreationDate=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyy").parse(personCdate);
        System.out.println("Junit Test personCreationDate : "+ personCreationDate);
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        System.err.println("Date parsing exception");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    personPer.setCreationDate(personCreationDate);

    session.insert(personPer);
```

DRL -
   Rule "Person check"

```
pp: PersonPer(pCreationDate:CreationDate)
....
when: 
...
(
...

 Date($now : time) from Calendar.getInstance().getTime()
 pp: PersonPer(pCreationDate:CreationDate after[90] $now) <--- This    doesn't work
```

...

```
 Then: 
  System.out.println("Person date : " + pCreationDate); 
   drools.addError(...);
   END

 12:32:55 ERROR Error: [ERR 102] Line 141:5 mismatched input 'pp' in rule   "Representative Checks"
  12:32:55 ERROR Error: Parser returned a null Package
```

1) The comparison between the person creation date and current date is not working. Please advise.
2) also, any suggestion how to make 90 days - configurable - so that it can be passed through business/Configuration files - using microservices.

Comment: Were you aware that `Date`, `SimpleDateFormat` and `Calendar` are long outdated? I recommend you look into [`java.time`, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/). It’s much nicer to work with.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks. I will have a look. Just trying to make it work with Drools 5.

Currently the Person java function returns the date in Wed Jun 06 21:55:44 GMT 2018 format.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by creating a drool file function for date calculation. Passing the month value as parameter to the function, the parameter being a fact variable passed from Java program as Object inserted in the state(ful) session.